# How can I compare two columns of different lengths from two dataframes to check for matching values in R?

Tags: r

I have two dataframes that look something like this:

```
df1

df2 <- data.frame(col1 = c(1,4,5,7), col2 = c("a","c","f", "g"))
df2

df1
 col1 col2
1    1    a
2    2    b
3    3    c
4    4    d
5    5    e
6    6    f
7    7    g
df2
 col1 col2
1    1    a
2    2    c
3    3    f
4    4    g
5   10    z
```

I want to compare the values in col2 of each df and line up the columns of each df by the matches to get this:

```
   col1 col2 col1.1 col2.1
1    1    a      1      a
2    2    b     NA   <NA>
3    3    c      2      c
4    4    d     NA   <NA>
5    5    e     NA   <NA>
6    6    f      3      f
7    7    g      4      g
```

Where ideally, the missing values from df1 are dropped and the missing values from df2 are filled in with NAs. Ultimately, I want to calculate what percent of the values in col2 of df1 have a match in col2 of df2.

Answer (score 0):

Use `left_join` from dplyr

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% 
  left_join(df2, by="col2", keep = TRUE)
```

output:

```
 col1.x col2.x col1.y col2.y
1      1      a      1      a
2      2      b     NA   <NA>
3      3      c      2      c
4      4      d     NA   <NA>
5      5      e     NA   <NA>
6      6      f      3      f
7      7      g      4      g
```

To get the percentage of match

```
out <- df1 %>% 
  left_join(df2, by="col2", keep = TRUE) 

out %>% 
  filter(col2.x == col2.y) %>% 
  nrow()/nrow(out)*100
```

Result:

```
[1] 57.14286
```

If you want the % of match as a new column:

```
df1 %>% 
  left_join(df2, by="col2", keep = TRUE) %>% 
  mutate(percentage_match = sum(col2.x == col2.y, na.rm = TRUE)/nrow(.)*100)
```

output:

```
  col1.x col2.x col1.y col2.y percentage_match
1      1      a      1      a         57.14286
2      2      b     NA   <NA>         57.14286
3      3      c      2      c         57.14286
4      4      d     NA   <NA>         57.14286
5      5      e     NA   <NA>         57.14286
6      6      f      3      f         57.14286
7      7      g      4      g         57.14286
```